# how do I access the angular-ui/ui-router $state object from a global function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm handling a click by navigating to the appropriate state with the $state.go function, but since it's a global function, I don't know how to access that functionality, since $state isn't global. Also, I happen to be in a nested state, i.e. "home.schedule", and I want to jump over to another nested state from a different root, i.e. "customer.info", so even when I cache the $state object in angular $scope, it won't let me do what I need to do.

Please advise!

BTW, I'm a big fan of ui-router. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Injecting $state whereever you want should work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It's best to assign the $state to the $rootScope upon start of the application in the .run block:

```
angular.module('app')
  .run('$rootScope', '$state' , function ( $rootScope, $state){
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
  });
```

This allows you access the $state object anywhere including in nested states.

Comment: Thanks, David. Based on your answer, I tracked down the guidance in the docs: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#note-about-using-state-within-a-template

Comment: Pretty. I have been trying to find this out for a long time.